# Get a gif picture from website but after save it become a static picture

Tags: .net, asp.net, image, gif

i Get a  gif picture from website but after save  it become a static picture,my code is:

```
string picurl = "http://www.ifanr.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/J1D2AYQV.gif";
string savepath=@"D:\test.gif";
string imgExt = picurl.Substring(picurl.LastIndexOf("."), picurl.Length - picurl.LastIndexOf("."));
WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(picurl);
wreq.Timeout = 10000;
HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();
Stream s = wresp.GetResponseStream();
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
if (imgExt == ".gif")
{
img.Save(savepath, ImageFormat.Gif);
}
img.Dispose();
s.Dispose();
```

who can help me? thanks!

Comment: What is a "Static Picture"? A GIF that has no animation frames?

Comment: Do _not_ convert it to an `Image`, but save the binary stream directly to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
   {
      wc.DownloadFile("http://www.ifanr.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/J1D2AYQV.gif", @"D:\test.gif");
   }
```

Your gif image will be kept intact.